# Modify Qt's shared library code while application starts

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create some kind of a server which allows me to start Qt's applications on remote machine via web browser.

I'm wondering it is possible to change/hide some symbols from Qt library (I thought about QApplication or QCoreApplication) without making any changes in code of application (I assume that it is already compiled and uses Qt shared library) and compiling my whole tailor-made Qt libs?

The reason why I need to do this is because I want to install my own specific EventFilter to QApplication and also be able to push my own created events to Qt application.

*It also would be great if the solution could be used on all platforms :D*

**P.S.** I know that it will not be possible I could subclass QApplication and modify all Qt apps to use my derived class but I would like to do this more craftily. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool [GammaRay](http://www.kdab.com/gammaray) does all kinds of injecting code into Qt methods at runtime to attach and debug running Qt applications. You might want to have a look at its code base to see how it is done.